What does liquidity really mean in uniswap V3?
I'm studyning Uniswyap protocols and I'm having a hard time to understand the concept of concentrated liquidity. I do understand the idea of choosing the price of assets to be the ratio of X and Y on a curve like xy = K, and I do know that liquidity has to do with the avaible number of tokens X and Y. For example, if there are only 1 token X and 5 token Y then there's a lower liquidity than if there were 5 X and 10 Y,but why the formula for liquidity is the geometric mean L = sqrt(xy) ?
Okay, i know in Uniswap V3 you discretize the space of prices with ticks and you can choose within which range of prices you want your resources to be used to provide liquidity, so for instance if i've provided 5 X tokens and 10 Y tokens and tell that i only want to trade under a interval [p_min,p_max] then my tokens will not be avaible for exchanging outside the interval, but why the hell this means that my capital is more efficient ? If i use uniswap V2 and let my tokens be used to exchange at any price how is this making my capital underused?

i atempted to write an answer but your question includes multiple questions. answer of each question will be very long. before I vote to close the question, I suggest breaking your question down into separate posts, each addressing one specific aspect. This will make it easier for everybody

In Uniswap v2, liquidity was spread across the entire price range from 0 to ∞, meaning much of the liquidity is not used efficiently, especially for assets that trade within a narrower price range. think about DAI-USDC pool.
 Liquidity is spread thinly across the entire range.

|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
0  0.5  0.9  0.95  0.99  1  1.01  1.05  1.1  1.5  2

Transactions mostly occur between 0.99-1.01 price range. That means only ~0.50% of the liqudity is used and 99.5% of liquidity is untouched. with concentrated liquidity feature, Liquidity provider can choose the specific price range. so liquidity will look like this:
|                   |---|---|---|
                   0.99 1  1.01
Liquidity is concentrated within the relevant range.

since we have higher liquidity in this price range:

Trades occurring within the $0.99 to $1.01 range will experience lower price impact and slippage due to the higher liquidity density.

Higher trading volumes within the relevant range result in more frequent fee generation for the Liqudity Provider. The more trades that occur within their specified liquidity range, the more fees they earn.


in Defi, liquidity is a measure of how easily assets can be bought or sold in the market without causing significant price changes. High liquidity reduces the volatility of asset prices by absorbing large trades without causing significant price changes.
Now we need a metric to represent this measure. Uniswap uses geometric mean.

How this liquidity (v3) is calculated?
